# Show object items except 2 specific items

Tags: javascript

I have an object that contains some values i want to show all items & values except two of them

```
My obj = {Username=[maher@wizy.io], question1=[sddsd], question2=[Option 1], question3=[USA], question4=[yes], Timestamp=[6/23/2015 12:15:00]}
```

I want to show all except Username & Timestamp.

I have tried this but i don't get what i want

```
for (var value in e.namedValues) {
 if (e.namedValues[key] != "Username" && e.namedValues[key] != "Timestamp"){

    Logger.log(value);
  }
}
```

Comment: if (value != "Username" && value != "Timestamp")

Comment: @PalSingh write an answer rather than a comment.

Comment: thanks a lot and if i want to show the key + the value i mean something like 
question1 : sddsd
question2 : Option 1
question3 : USA
question4 : yes

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To use key in condition, you are suppose to use `value` to compare

Change your if condition like below:

```
if (value != "Username" && value != "Timestamp") {
    Logger.log(value);
}
```

to show key + value:

```
console.log(value +": "+ e.namedValues[value]);
```

Answer (score 2):

As Pal Singh suggested, all of your values are in "var value" so what your are ought to do is to check the following

```
if(value != "UserName" && value != "Timestamp")
{
    Logger.log(value);
}
```

You do not need to check for the key, it doesn't contain any value.

Answer (score 1):

> thanks a lot and if i want to show the key + the value i mean something like question1 : sddsd question2 : Option 1 question3 : USA question4 : yes

To do this you can `console.log(value + " : " + e.namedValues[value]);`